# pgbouncer - could not connect to server: Address already in use (0x00002740/10048)

Tags: postgresql, libpq, pgbouncer

I have an app using libpq to connect to postgresql server and using pgbouncer as connection pool

```
    if (pconn == nullptr) {
        pconn = PQconnectdb(chrConnectStr);
    }
    if (PQstatus(pconn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {

        //If it fails, try to connect once
        pconn = PQconnectdb(chrConnectStr);
        //Make an error if it still fails
        if (PQstatus(pconn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {  
            //Error sometimes occurred here when test with concurrent connection
            return S_FALSE;
        }
    }
    ....... 
    //When connection OK, doing SQL execution
    //Close connection after finish
    PQFinish(pconn);
```

Every thing fine when I running one app instance.
But when I test with multi instances concurrent (about 5 instances), some times I got `CONNECTION_BAD` status

At that time I checked `PQerrorMessage(conn)` and see error message :

```
could not connect to server: Address already in use (0x00002740/10048)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 6543?
```

Here is pgbouncer config

```
[databases]
food = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=MyDB auth_user=MyUser

[pgbouncer]
listen_port = 6543
listen_addr = *
auth_type = md5
auth_file = D:\PostgreSQL\pgbouncer\users.txt
admin_users = MyUser
syslog = 1
default_pool_size = 100
server_reset_query = DEALLOCATE ALL
```

Also in `postgres.conf` I setting: `max_connections = 500`

Answer (score 0):

From `man 2 bind`:

> `EADDRINUSE`
>        (Internet domain sockets) The port number was specified as zero in the socket address structure, but, upon attempting to bind to
>        an ephemeral port, it was determined that all port numbers in the ephemeral port range are currently in use.  See the discussion
>        of `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` `ip(7)`.

And from `man 7 ip`:

> `/proc` interfaces
>       The  IP  protocol supports a set of `/proc` interfaces to configure some global parameters.  The parameters can be accessed by reading or
>       writing files in the directory `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/`.  Interfaces described as Boolean take  an  integer  value,  with  a  nonzero  value
>       ("true") meaning that the corresponding option is enabled, and a zero value ("false") meaning that the option is disabled.
>
> [...]
>
> `ip_local_port_range` (since Linux 2.2)
>      This file contains two integers that define the default local port range allocated to sockets that are not explicitly bound to a
>      port number—that is, the range used for ephemeral ports.  An ephemeral port is allocated to a socket in  the  following  circumstances:
>
> - the port number in a socket address is specified as 0 when calling `bind(2)`;
> - `listen(2)` is called on a stream socket that was not previously bound;
> - `connect(2)` was called on a socket that was not previously bound;
> - `sendto(2)` is called on a datagram socket that was not previously bound.
>
>   Allocation of ephemeral ports starts with the first number in ip_local_port_range and ends with the second number.  If the range
>     of ephemeral ports is exhausted, then the relevant system call returns an error (but see BUGS).
>
>   Note that the port range in `ip_local_port_range` should not conflict with the ports used by masquerading (although  the  case  is
>     handled).   Also,  arbitrary  choices may cause problems with some firewall packet filters that make assumptions about the local
>     ports in use.  The first number should be at least greater than 1024, or better, greater than 4096, to avoid clashes  with  well
>     known ports and to minimize firewall problems.

Looks to me like you are running out of ephemeral ports. Do you have that many connections? Perhaps increasing the ephemeral port range will help.